# Problema em correr webapp depois de reinstalação de windows 10. Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013

Depois de reinstalação de windows 10 e do Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web um projeto que antes funcionava passou a indicar o seguinte erro:

> Não foi possível carregar o ficheiro ou assemblagem 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ou uma das respectivas dependências. A definição do manifesto de assemblagem localizada não corresponde à referência de assemblagem. (Excepção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.IO.FileLoadException: Não foi possível carregar o ficheiro ou assemblagem 'System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' ou uma das respectivas dependências. A definição do manifesto de assemblagem localizada não corresponde à referência de assemblagem. (Excepção de HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Alguma vez passaram por isso? Qual a solução encontrada?

Comment: Você fez a instalação completa do Visual Studio?

Comment: Sim, fiz a instalação completa @jbueno